# Bash get specific file with name in all directories and run script

Tags: bash

This is my scenario, I have a root folder called A, which contains folders B,C,D with n possibilities.  Each one of those folders have a bash script.  How can I get those bash scripts and run them using bash script.

```
A/B/run.sh
A/C/run.sh
A/D/run.sh
```

Comment: do they require any arguments? And does order matter?

Comment: order does not matter and they don't require any arguments

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Comment: Thanks for the note I will do that next time, yeah I didn't even know where to begin with since I didn't have any code yet was struggling to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easy :)

```
eval "$(ls A/*/run.sh)"
```

ls will return a list of file with path to your scripts. (you could use find too)

the " " around the $() will make sure the result keeps new lines

eval will execute the returned lines as a script.

Mind you if there are spaces in the names of your script and stuff this can be a brittle solution. But if it looks like what you have shown, that should work fine.

this is output for an example:

```
 ~/ eval "$(ls */run.sh)"
 I am running and my name is: one/run.sh
 I am running and my name is: two/run.sh
```

the run.sh scripts are:

```
 echo "I am running and my name is: $0"
```

Comment: @yetanotherposter : The other solution is more general and you can easily accommodate non-standard directory names in that.

Comment: @Rob : This will fail for file say "my_*new_line*_directory". But yes, this is the most obvious way to do it :-)

Comment: I would have thought that a `for` loop would be the most obvious way yo do it. This solution appears to be an implementation of the very first warning on the [bash pitfalls list](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 5):

With find :

```
find . -name *.sh -type f -exec bash -c '[[ -x {} ]] || chmod u+x {}; {}' \;
```

For each `*.sh` found :

- check if file has execute permissions
- if not set execute permission for user
- execute script

Comment: This should be the best recursive solution. :-)

Comment: I have found bash's `globstar` feature to be quite a bit faster at finding things recursively than `find`. YMMV. +1 from me anyway, since this is superior to the embedded `ls` solution.